# How to Start Application with Multiple Routers?

Tags: backbone.js

How should one load/start an application that has multiple routers? Should one simply load and initialize **all** routers in the "*app.js*" file? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem using multiple routers as long as you do not define a default or catch all route in more than one. Then you won't know what's going on.

In any case, just start up each one in sequence. They won't do anything until you navigate.